# В GitHub Desktop не могу сделать клонирование

Tags: github

Может кто сталкивался, не работает программа GitHub Desktop, когда пытаюсь клонировать выдает ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке выполнить клонирование появляется ошибка. Добавил приложение в исключение к антивирусу, папку куда клонирую тоже. Права на ПК администраторские. Но похоже, что ошибка не в компьютере т.к. пробовал на другом, тоже самое выдает. 
Может знает из-за чего такое возможно?

Comment: У вас же в ошибке написано: "unable to access" с сетью все в порядке? адрес репы? репу вообще клонировать можно? или скачать вручную хотя б. через консоль клонирование проходит?

Comment: сетью все в порядке? - да, сеть работает. Репу вообще клонировать можно? - можно, это учебный проект, я его форкнул в свой репозиторий и его пытаюсь клонировать. Обращу внимание, что это только в программе GitHub Desktop которая необходима для учебного проекта. Пробовал в Гит кракен, там клонирование прошло нормально. Но я первый раз столкнулся с Гитом и ещё не понимаю его, мне сейчас важно хотя бы освоить рекомендованную программу.  Мой репозиторий https://github.com/Multikus/387003-technomart

Comment: Кстати а что это за слеш после .git? его по идее быть не должно

Comment: На этот вопрос не могу ответить, специально не добавлял его. В Гит хабе я нажимало клонировать, открыть URL в приложении он сам уже туда URL подставлял.

Comment: Когда добавляю ссылку к репозиторию но последнего слеша нет. Вот так ссылка выглядит https://github.com/Multikus/387003-technomart.git   на скрине это он сам добавляет.